How to enter in position every time signal generates in trading view Pine script
I want to enter every time signal generate but problem is its triggering entry only once during open position. I want it to enter every time no matter how many open positions. I am not sure why its waiting for close of previous open position.
also i want to close all at just 2 minutes before the end of trade day (15:29).
.......................................
BuyA=  (high > outC3) and (((outC1 > outC2) and BreakOUT_1) or ((outC1 > outC2) and BreakOUT_2) and not GreenLast4) ExitBuyA = BuyA[17] strategy.entry("BuyA", strategy.long, when = BuyA) strategy.close("BuyA", when= ExitBuyA)
..........................................
all possible scenarios i knew

By default, you can only have one open position. If you want to have multiple open positions in the same direction, you should change the pyramiding setting.
Add pyramiding=99 to your strategy() call or change it via Settings -> Properties.

Yes i found this and it worked... Thanks
